# Maximum alternating slice in an array

Tags: java, algorithm, array

I'm working on the problem:

> Given array with positive and negative values, return the **maximum alternating slice size**; two elements are alternating if they have different signs, zero is treated as both negative and positive.
>
> Time complexity: \$O(N)\$
>
> Space complexity: \$O(1)\$

I developed a working code and would like to know if there is any method to make the code shorter or faster.

```
public static int maxSizeAlterSlice(int[] a){
    int max_size_so_far = -1;
    int cur_max_size = -1;
    if(a.length == 1)
        return 1;
    int startInd = 0;
    int endInd = 0;
    int i=1;
    int compareInd=0;
    while(i<a.length){
        if((a[compareInd]>=0 && a[i]<=0)||(a[compareInd]<=0 && a[i]>=0)){
            compareInd=i;
            endInd++;
            i++;
        }else{
            cur_max_size = endInd-startInd+1;
            if(max_size_so_far<cur_max_size){
                max_size_so_far = cur_max_size;
            }
            startInd = i;
            compareInd=startInd;
            endInd=startInd;
            i=startInd+1;
        }
    }
    return max_size_so_far;
}
```

Comment: I get the result `-1` for the array `{-1, 1}` with your code ...

Comment: I missed the case if it's all the array is an alternating slice!

Comment: Are you going to fix this? CR is about reviewing *working* code. – Btw, does  `-1, 0, 1` count as an alternating sequence of length 3?

Comment: If zero is both negative and positive; are `1, 0, 1` and `1, 0, -1` both valid alternating sequences?

Comment: yes I'm going to fix it. Otherwise, the example of -1,0,1 wasn't given the exercise, so I don't know is it alternating or not. I think that it's not because we have to consider 0 as negative or positive for every one instance of zero.

Comment: Assigning the sign to zero in each comparision (both to the left and to the right neighbor) separately causes a weird situation that `1,0,-1` can be considered an alternating sequence, as zero would be negative compared to `1` and positive compared to `-1`. OTOH assigning it a constant sign requires a double analysis: the very same digit can either be a (negative) tail of a `...1,0` sequence or a (positive) head of `0,-1,....` and you can't know in advance which assignment is more profitable.

Comment: Even more complicated situation arises with multiple zeros `...,0,0,0,...`

Comment: I think the number of zeros as well as the previous sign before the 1st zero should be tracked..

Comment: @SarahM: Note that incorporating feedback from an answer into the question is *not* allowed on this site, please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)* and *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: I saw someone doing it before without a remark on that.. ok I will remove.

Comment: I've rolled back you question to Rev 2, as you still included some of wildbagel's advice in your question.

Answer (score 4):

Hmm. I'm not sure about faster, but you can shorten your code by about 6 lines by doing things a little more efficiently.

First, I'd move your two initializations at the top to be below your if statement. That if statement short-circuits the whole function (which is fine), but since the statement doesn't use those two variables, we shouldn't instantiate them unless it fails to return: that's more efficient. I would also return `a.length` rather than `1` (to eliminate a 'magic number').

Next, you can eliminate the cur_max_size variable and its usage. Remove the declaration, then take the whole block involving cur_max_size and max_size_so_far and replace with this:

```
max_size_so_far = Math.max(endInd - startInd + 1, max_size_so_far);
```

Next, there are two places where you can use `i++` inside of another statement, rather than having it stand on its own. `i++` means "increment after the original value is used" so this is safe:

- Inside of your if conditional (inside the while), delete `i++;` and change the first statement to be `compareInd = i++;`
- Inside of your else statement, remove `i = startInd + 1;` and change the `startInd=i;` line to be `startInd = i++;`. (Yes, the logic works out.)

Answer (score 2):

- Give your operators some breathing space.
- **`compareInd`** is confusing. Logically, it is always equal to `i - 1`, but it is quite hard to infer from the code. Better drop it entirely, and explicitly use `i - 1`.
- **`endInd`** is equally confusing. It also follows `i`, and therefore is unnecessary as well.
- The `if...else` construct begs to become a loop:

  ```
      while (i < a.length) {
          while (alternating(i)) {
              i++;
          }
          length = i - startInd;
          ....
          startInd = i++;
      }
  ```

  Now it becomes obvious that the outer `while` is in fact a `for`:

  ```
      for (i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
          while (alternating(i)) {
              i++;
          }
          ....
          startInd = i;
      }
  ```
- An alternation condition could be simplified as `a[i-1] * a[i] <= 0`, but it is a matter of taste.

Comment: Depending on the range of the given numbers, `a[i-1] * a[i]` can overflow. One could cast them to `long` to be on the safe side.